# Sub-query after WHERE works when alone, but not as sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
USE [AdventureWorks2014]
GO

SELECT PERSON.FirstName, PERSON.LastName, SP.*
FROM [Person].[Person] PERSON, [Sales].[SalesPerson] SP
WHERE (SELECT TotalDue
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader) >
    (SELECT AVG(TotalDue)
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader);
```

If I run this, I get the error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

However, if I remove everything between "GO" and the WHERE (also removing the first set of parentheses), the query runs fine, and gives me an answer of something over 4000. (Which sounds right to me.)

I am new to this, so this is really kicking my butt. I just know that I'm missing something really simple, too, but I just can NOT see it right now, and I've been fighting it for long enough that my brain has gone to mush. (Running SQL Server Express 2014, if that turns out to be important, by the way.)

EDIT: As per Ted's comments, let me rephrase the question, now that I'm significantly more awake, and also state that I am looking for GUIDANCE, and not for someone to write it for me, because I learn nothing if you guys do it for me.

I am using the AdventureWorks database supplied by Microsoft for SQL Server for so many years. I need to retrieve the first and last name from the Person.Person table, and all information from the Sales.Salesperson table. However, the only ones I want to display are the ones that have an amount in the Sales.SalesOrderHeader.TotalDue column that is GREATER than the average of the entire Sales.SalesOrderHeader.TotalDue column. The Person.Person and Sales.SalesPerson share the BusinessEntityID key, and TerritoryID is shared between Sales.SalesOrderHeader and Sales.SalesPerson. If I use a JOIN of any sort, it enters an endless loop that I have to stop manually.

If I comment out the outer query, the query returns an answer of 4012. But all attempts I have made since then to get that data to affect my outer join have either thrown various error messages or endless loops.

If more information is needed about this issue, please tell me - I am trying to learn both SQL and how to properly ask the questions. (Not pissing Ted off is a side benefit.)

Comment: what you are trying to achieve by your query

Comment: You Need to tell what should be done with totalDue

Comment: your where clause has no reference to the selected table, it will not filter any single thing

Comment: You need a correlated sub-qeury.

Comment: add Table relationship other wise this will be difficult to Ans your question

Comment: Okay - as I said, I'm new to this, so I know I'm missing something simple. The idea is to grab only the information requested in the outer query, but filtered through to find a certain subset of those people. Specifically, the people that have a TotalDue amount that is larger than the average of TotalDue. I don't need to display TotalDue. Tried an INNER JOIN and got an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the statement below:

```
(SELECT TotalDue FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader) 
> 
(SELECT AVG(TotalDue) FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader);
```

`(SELECT TotalDue FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader)` can possibly return more than one row while `(SELECT AVG(TotalDue) FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader)` will always return one.

You cannot compare 1 with many using the `>` operator.

Perhaps you mean to use `max` or `min`:

```
(SELECT MAX(TotalDue) FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader) 
> 
(SELECT AVG(TotalDue) FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader);
```

Comment: I need to compare the TotalDue amount from each person against the average of the TotalDue column.

Comment: @KeithMcComb - Please, try and see this from my perspective:
1. I have no knowledge of your `schema` (`tables`, `columns`) because you haven't provided any info.
2. I don't know how `person` and `salesperson` are connected (`primary key`, `foreign key`)
3. You are unable to describe your problem in plain English, and
4. It seems that you are looking for someone to write the code for you and that pisses me off...

Comment: Ted - someone gave me the data dictionary for AdventureWorks, and it cleared some crap up for me - I was unaware that a Key in the SalesOrderHeader was basically a rename of BusinessEntityID. Once I knew that, I could do an INNER JOIN that didn't cause an infinite loop.

Comment: @KeithMcComb - understood, but you keep saying that the sql caused an infinite loop and that's just not true. there are no infinite loops in sql selects unless you are talking about a while loop in a stored procedure or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery is returning more than one result, this means it cannot be directly compared to anything.

To get around this (although it might not work how you want):

```
USE [AdventureWorks2014]
GO

SELECT PERSON.FirstName, PERSON.LastName, SP.*
FROM [Person].[Person] PERSON, [Sales].[SalesPerson] SP
WHERE (SELECT TOP 1 TotalDue
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader) >
    (SELECT AVG(TotalDue)
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader);
```

Comment: Did mention that.. It's unclear what expected result is from OP

Comment: you guys kidding? the `WHERE` clause is not referenced to the main tables. it will return all the results or no results

Comment: I don't need to display the TotalDue amount, which is why I don't list it in the outer query. But I need to filter out and show only those who have a TotalDue amount greater than the average of that same column. Basically, I need to compare a column against an average of itself.

Comment: Keith you can filter it out without including it in the resultset, I believe using HAVING

Answer (score 0):

I think @Ted's answer describes the problem with your query and here's my guess at what you might be wanting your query to do:

```
SELECT PERSON.FirstName, PERSON.LastName, SP.*
  FROM [Person].[Person] PERSON, [Sales].[SalesPerson] SP
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 'true'
                  FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
                 HAVING MAX(TotalDue) > AVG(TotalDue) );
```